# Conditional zstyle format (color) for git branch name in zsh prompt (using prezto)

Tags: zsh, prompt, prezto

I am switching to zsh from bash and one thing that I'm used to is having the git branch name in my prompt coloured to reflect whether the branch is clean or not. So if my branch is `main` and it's clean, `main` appears in green, otherwise `main` appears in red.

It feels like this should be simple to do, but I'm struggling to interpret [the documentation](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/tree/master/modules/git#git-1).

This is the default configuration in the theme I'm using:

```
zstyle ':prezto:module:git:info:branch' format ' %%B%F{2}%b%f%%b'
```

I can't find any references to being able to put conditional statements in the format strings.

From the documentation, it looks like maybe there is a way to use subcontexts to achieve this:

```
zstyle ':prezto:module:git:info:context:subcontext' format 'string'
```

but there isn't any reference to what a subcontext actually is. As a fairly random guess about what a subcontext is, I tried this, but it makes no difference. Not surprising as I could find no reference to any subcontexts of branch in the code, but this at least semantically describes the result I am aiming for!

```
zstyle ':prezto:module:git:info:branch' format ' %%B%F{2}%b%f%%b'
zstyle ':prezto:module:git:info:branch:dirty' format ' %%B%F{1}%b%f%%b'
```

The zstyle statements are made during the setup of the prompt, so there is no way to use conditional logic (i.e. if-else) to control which zstyle statement is run at that time based on a specific branch.

What's the obvious way to handle this that I'm missing?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but: Instead of trying to figure out Prezto's Git prompt API, it might actually be simpler to just roll your own Git prompt. It's really not that hard. See, for example, my prompt here: https://github.com/marlonrichert/.config/blob/b97c3ec377b687b8a73209920a53863a507c65ca/zsh/.zshrc#L55

Comment: @MarlonRichert Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm largely happy with all the functionality I've gained from Prezto for free that is community maintained. That's actually one of the things that attracted me to zsh in the first place. It's just this one outstanding piece of customisation and I'll have completed my migration!